# What plant do these seeds belong to?

Tags: seeds

I harvested these seeds from an indigenous garden, so this plant is likely indigenous to South Africa, potentially Cape Town.

It was a bushy plant with an abundance of these seeds in clumps all over the foliage, mostly at a height of 1 to 2 meters high. Inside the papery seed covering there is a tiny seed less than a mm in diameter.

Do you know what tree or bush it belongs to?

[image]

Comment: A photo of the actual plant that produced these would make ID a lot easier...

Comment: I will get a photo of the bush and add it to this to help!